# Is ${n\choose k}2^k$ asymptotically equivalent to ${2n\choose k}$?

Tags: inequality, asymptotics

Given $n$ and $k$ where $k=o(n)$. Is ${n\choose k}2^k$ asymptotically equivalent to ${2n\choose k}$? Or is there an inequality relationship between the two. My intuition tells me that they must be close because we have the inequalities ${n\choose k}2^k\geq(2n/k)^k$ and ${2n\choose k}\geq(2n/k)^k$.

Comment: You can try writing them using factorials and then use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: For **fixed** *k*, it's easy to prove that it's correct. However, for varying $k$, no. Let $n=k^2$ and use Stirling's formula to prove the limit of the quotient is $\exp(1/4)$.